# Most efficient way to access 2D Maps (Maps of Maps) in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm implementing the WeightedSlopeOne prediciton algorithm for recommender system and at some point in the code I need to have 2 2D maps, one `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>>` and one `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>>`

As you can understand accessing these and assigning values is a cumbersome procedure:

```
//The following 20 lines are 1 line in Python. Sigh...
HashMap<Integer, Integer> freqsForItem1 = frequencies.get(curItemID);
//See if we have a value for curItemID
if (freqsForItem1 == null) {
    freqsForItem1 = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    freqsForItem1.put(curItemID_2, 1);
    frequencies.put(curItemID, freqsForItem1);
}
else {//See if we have a value for curItemID+curItemID_2
    Integer freqForItem1Item2 = freqsForItem1.get(curItemID_2);
    if (freqForItem1Item2 == null) {
        //If we don't have a value for item1+item2 we just put 1
        freqsForItem1.put(curItemID_2, 1);
    }
    else {//We already have a value for curItemID+curItemID_2
        //So we just increment it
        freqsForItem1.put(curItemID_2, freqForItem1Item2 + 1);
    }
}
```

So what should I be using here instead of a `Map<K1, Map<K2, V>>`, or if there is no better data structure available what is a better way to access and change the values of such a Map?

Comment: Have you looked at using Multimap in Guava?

Comment: I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't use any external libraries, if any exists.

Comment: A Multimap should beequivalent to a __Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>__ (eg multiple values for a key), not to what the OP needs (eg two levels of keys)

Comment: @Jack: Doh, you're right - my apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a map of maps, you can create a new, immutable class (with [properly implemented `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27581/139010)) that stores the two integer keys, and use *that* as the key for a simpler map.

```
class MyKey {
    int first;
    int second;
    // etc...
}

Map<MyKey, Integer> freqs = new HashMap<MyKey, Integer();
```

This will greatly simplify accessing & assigning values, and even moreso if you decide you need to make your key more complex.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Table` from Google's `Guava` to do this without worrying of implementation.

Check Guava Page: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table

Comment: As Jack said above: "A Multimap should be equivalent to a Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> (eg multiple values for a key), not to what the OP needs (eg two levels of keys) "

Comment: @Bar I have not answered about "Multimap" but "Table", these are entirely different classes!

Comment: @MichalBorek I think this bit of the docs makes it clear that a `Table` is very map-like: "`rowMap()`, which views a `Table<R, C, V>` as a `Map<R, Map<C, V>>`. Similarly, `rowKeySet()` returns a `Set<R>`."

Comment: @MichalBorek you're right sorry. Still, I was hoping for a solution that doesn't use external libraries so I chose the other answer. Upvoted for visibility though.

Answer (score -1):

so your key is an integer in both dimensions. why dont you use a

```
HashMap<Integer, Double> []
```

instead? or at least an

```
ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Double>>
```

Would be much more performant

Comment: Why do you think this would provide better performance? I don't think the OP is concerned with code performance, anyway, so much as complexity of the code that uses the data structure.

Comment: because a comparison of two objects (Integer) by hash is much slower than a plain comparison between two ints. maybe i misunderstood something, but i think efficiency includes performance.

Comment: Any "slowness" in the code is not going to arise from that, here.